# Do I need a passport to visit Edinburgh in Scotland from elsewhere in the UK?

Tags: uk, scotland, spanish-citizens

I'm visiting Scotland for the first time this week, Edinburgh. I've lived in the UK for over 10 years but my nationality is Spanish. I only have a Spanish passport.

I'm also traveling by train.

Do I need a passport to enter Scotland **and** stay in my booked hotel?

Comment: Enter Scotland: Definitely not, by train. Hotel, not sure, but I don't remember ever showing a passport myself going to a hotel in the UK. Since I'm not sure on the second point I'll let someone else answer it.

Comment: I have never been asked for ID on a British train even when traveling on a non-transferable BritRail pass. Great Britain has been a single country for most purposes, including border control, since the [Act of Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acts_of_Union_1707) went into effect in 1707. You may need some form of ID to check into a hotel, but that will be just like staying at a hotel in England.

Comment: It should be pointed out that Edinburgh is *in* the UK.

Answer (score 13):

Most hotels in the UK do not ask for an ID when you check in, but I think I have been asked for one at times.
If you have your Spanish National ID card, bring that, if not bring your passport.
If you are not happy with taking your passport, call the hotel and ask whether they require it.

There is no border between England and Scotland and therefor you do not need to show a passport there.
Whether you need a passport in the train depends on your ticket. I do not know any train tickets in the UK where you need a passport, but there might some.
If you buy online and have a home print, you might need your passport or ID card, read the print on the ticket.

Comment: The only train that might require a passport or ID I could think of might be London St Pancras International to Ashford in Kent on a Eurostar.

Comment: Journeys from St Pancreas to Ebbsfleet/Ashford use domestic Southeastern trains. Eurostar passengers go through French immigration before boarding.

Comment: I am not indicating that you need a passport on the trains from London to Scotland. But there might be home print tickets (if not yet maybe in the future) which ask for the person traveling to have an ID to use it. Happens in other EU countries.

Comment: It would be more likely in the UK that if you need something accompanying a home-print ticket it would be the credit card you used to pay for it. With the exception of purchasing alcohol there are very few things in the UK for which you're expected to show ID.

Answer (score 9):

There are no international borders involved. London to Edinburgh is a domestic train that requires no id unless you're using a print at home ticket.

The hotel is supposed to check and record passport or national identity card information of foreign guests, but in practice this rarely happens.

No and unlikely. Call them to check.